# Fetch api does not work in webextensions

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, fetch-api, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm experimenting firefox webextensions. I'd like to make HTTP requests using the fetch API after submitting a form. The problem is that the fetch request is not doing anything.

Here is the data extracted from my manifest.json:

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "test.html"
  },
"permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
 ],
```

Here is my test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my test.js:

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", fetchTest);
function fetchTest() {
    console.log("TEST");

    fetch('https://httpbin.org/get')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

When I click on the submit button of my form, I see that my function `fetchTest` is called because I can see the "TEST" message in the console. However, I have no requests coming from the browser in the "Network" panel, and I have no error in the console, it's as if the fetch() never happened.

Then, I tried to do the same thing with xhr:

```
function fetchTest() {
    console.log("TEST");

    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', 'https://httpbin.org/get', false);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    req.send(null);
    console.log(req);
}
```

With this version, everything is working just fine. I see the request in the "Network" panel and I have the data in my console.

Am I using the fetch API wrong ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Does anything change if you replace `type="submit"` with `type="button"` in HTML and `"sumbit"` with `"click"` in code? Using a `submit` input is a bad idea at least in Chrome; maybe FF is more tolerant to it, but worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work :) I cannot find the reason why it doesn't work with the submit event.
However, now the request is executed every time i click on a field.
I just added an id to the submit button and add the event listener on the button.

Comment: Added an explanation; I asked to test first because I wasn't sure if Firefox does anything differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an [input of type `submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit) is clicked, this causes a submit: since no other URL is specified, and no other form elements are there, the page is basically reloaded. Quoting MDN:

> `<input>` elements of type "submit" are rendered as buttons. When the `click` event occurs (typically because the user clicked the button), the user agent attempts to submit the form to the server.

Your `fetch`-based solution is fully asynchronous, which means your code starts, but is interrupted by the reload before it is complete.

Your XHR-based solution succeeds, since you invoke a synchronous form of XHR (with `false`); the reload is stalled until your code finishes, then it still reloads.

You don't want a reload anyway, which destroys your JS state; you could prevent it by calling `e.preventDefault()` from the handler, but semantically it's more correct *not* to use a `submit` button instead of doing brain surgery on its semantics.

Using `<input type="button">` (or better yet, `<button>`) would be the right (and cleaner) approach. Quoting MDN:

> `<input type="submit">` buttons are used to submit forms. If you want to create a custom button and then customize the behavior using JavaScript, you need to use `<input type="button">`, or better still, a `<button>` element.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now it makes sense :)