# in this extension , where is my fault?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The following code is from an extension I am writing. It is an extension that when you click on button it will show a notification.  However, when I run it, nothing happens when you press the button.

## Manifest File

```
{
    "manifest_version":2,

    "name":"NOTE",
    "description":"It is an example for using Notification",
    "version":"1.0",

    "browser_action":{
        "default_popup":"popup.html",
        "default_icon":{
            "16":"icon_16.png",
            "48":"icon_48.png",
            "128":"icon_128.png"
        }
    },

    "permissions": [
        "notifications"
    ]
}
```

## popupHtml

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>NOTIFICATION</title>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="change" type="submit" value="Notification" />
    </body>
</html>
```

popupJS // function is in this file:

```
$(function(){
    $('#change').click(function(){
        var opt ={
           type: "basic",
           title: "notification",
          message: "Total has been reset back to 0.",
           iconUrl: "icon_48.png"
        }
        chrome.notifications.create('change', opt, function () { }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Try changing from ".click(function().." to ".on('click', function() ..".  I would also suggest moving from "<input type="submit" to "<button type="button".."

Comment: I changed it but not working : 
$('#change').on('click',(function(){
        var opt ={
           type: "basic",
           title: "notification",
          message: "Total has been reset back to 0.",
           iconUrl: "icon_48.png"
        }
        chrome.notifications.create('change', opt, function () { });
    }));

Comment: @aminkargar It will be a good idea to change the subject of this question to something meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery before you load it. The order is significant:

```html
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

should be instead

```html
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

As mentioned, you should also [use `button` instead of `submit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47158888/934239).

You would be able to see this error if you properly debugged your popup; to do so, right-click the button and select "Inspect popup" to bring up Dev Tools for it.